# Using upper and lower case Scheme symbols, clarification needed

Tags: scheme

Why is it that when asking Scheme to interpret a symbol value with mixed case, only a lower case version is returned?

```
#;> 'HelloWorld
helloworld

#;> 'helloworld
helloworld
```

For the above example, i am using [sisc](http://sisc-scheme.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In some Scheme interpreters symbols are case-insensitive, it seems that's the case in SISC. That's implementation-dependent, and it's not consistent across different implementations. For instance, these are different symbols in Racket:

```
(equal? 'HelloWorld 'helloworld)
=> #f
```

According to this [FAQ](http://community.schemewiki.org/?scheme-faq-language):

> R5RS states that identifiers and symbols read via the Scheme reader (i.e. when reading Scheme programs) are case-insensitive and may get their case changed. Hence `(eq? 'a 'A)` is the same as `(EQ? 'a 'A)` and returns `#t`. Note though that it is considered bad style to write programs that rely on this, e.g. by defining a function `foo` and then calling it using `(Foo)` or `(FOO)`.

Comment: Interesting ... on my system the above returned `true`. Thanks Oscar!

Answer (score 2):

R5RS states that all symbols are case-insensitive and may get their case changed.

Note that some implementations handle this differently.. it's not required (but is common, as in in SISC) that `(eq? 'a 'A)` return `#t`, but it is required that if you define a function `a` that you be able to call it with `(A)`.

Answer (score 0):

Most versions of Scheme, just as its parent language Lisp, are case-insensitive, so the symbol can be interned any way the implementation wants to do it; most versions of Scheme and Lisp use upper-case symbols, but lower-case is also possible, as is whatever case is entered by the user. Since R6RS, most Scheme systems are case-sensitive and will intern the symbol exactly as it is entered.